# Using AND in Lisp

Tags: list, if-statement, lisp

I have two lists, p1 and p2, in a function and I would like to carry out another function if the first item in both lists is NULL. I have an IF statement but it doesn't work:

```
(defun poly (p1 p2)

(if ((and (car p1) (car p2)) nil )
    (princ (car p1))
)
```

Any ideas why it won't work?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: The first help would have been the error message that the compiler gave you, but you ignored it.  It should have told you something like "Error: `(and (car p1) (car p2))` is not an operator".  You really should show the error you are getting instead of hand-waving "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your forms appear to be nested improperly.

```
(if test true-branch &optional false-branch)
```

in this case is binding

```
       test          = ((and (car p1) (car p2)) nil)
       true-branch   = (princ (car p1))
       false-branch  = nil
```

you probably wanted

```
       (if (and (car p1) (car p2))
           nil
           (princ (car p1)))
```

which is more usually written as

```
       (unless (and (car p1) (car p2))
               (princ (car p1)))
```

which is somewhat strange because you know that `(car p1)` *may be* `nil` at that point, (except `(car p2)` could be `nil`), so it may then be the same as

```
        (unless (and (car p1) (car p2)) (princ nil))
```

half the time, so perhaps you meant rather like

```
       (when (and (car p1) (car p2)) (princ (car p1))
```

which is the same as

```
       (if (and (car p1) (car p2)) (princ (car p1)))
```

(but the use of `when` or `unless` helps others reading your code, so we won't have to puzzle over the forms to make sure that there isn't an “`else`-clause” hiding in there that we haven't noticed)

So, I'm not really sure what you're trying to do there.

⁂ Note on how your compiler will interpret what you've written a bit further:

```
  ((and (car p1) (car p2)) nil)
```

is a particularly problematic-looking form, because this is what will happen:

```
  (eval (car p1)) (eval (car p2))
```

let's call these results for now `cp1` and `cp2`

```
  (eval (and cp1 cp2))
```

OK, so if `cp1` (i.e. `(car p1)`) is `nil`, it has just become the value of the form; if it *is not* `nil`, then `cp2` will become the value of the form.

So, the results of this form are one of two things: `nil`, or `cp2` (which could be `nil`)
Let's call this result `f`

The next form outward, though, is the problem:

```
   (eval ((function f) nil))
```

You see, the `(and…)` form is in the `car` of the surrounding form, so the compiler is going to have to try to coërce the results of that form into a `funcall`able object, as though you'd called the function `function` on it.

Now, if `f` (i.e. `(and (car p1) (car p2))`) happens to be a reference to a function, *and* that function can be called with a single parameter, then you might be OK.

But the fact that you're trying to `princ` the results of `(car p1)` suggests that the contents are likely a `string`, `character`, or `number`, and none of those are going to return a function pointer when passed to `function`.

**Lesson to take home**: Watch your parentheses :-)

Also… the output from your compiler or debugger should probably have given you some strong hints about what was going wrong here. In future, it'd be quite helpful to show

- what parameters you're passing in to the function, and
- what your output from the compiler or debugger is that let you know you have a problem

Comment: So how would I change it so that it is only true if (car p1) AND (car p1) is nil?

Comment: Um, that is ambiguous in English; if you mean `(and (car p1) (not (car p2)))` (like: `(car p1) & ¬(car p2)` infix-style), then you might use `(if (and (car p1) (not (car p2))) (do-it))` (or `when`), but if you mean `(and (not (car p1)) (not (car p2)))` (like `(¬(car p1) & ¬(car p2))` – the latter is more clearly written as `(not (or (car p1) (car p2)))`… which would be `(unless (or (car p1) (car p2)) (do-something))`